# positional argument follows keyword argument Error when i try to group by

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Here's a snippet of my original dataset: [orignal dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bazEJ.png)

I wrote a code to split `KATS TIME` and made separate columns for `hour`, `mins` and `secs`.
Then I made another column for total price of the trades by the name `TOTAL_TRADE_RATE` by multiplying `TRADE_QTY` with `TRADE_RATE`.

Now i want to group the dataset by minutes, i.e., i want the values for each minute.
For that i'm using the groupby function with the following code:

`df = df.groupby(by=['TRADE_ENTRY_DATE'], ['SYMBOL_CODE'], as_index=False)['TOTAL_TRADE_RATE'].sum()`

But it's giving an error:  `positional argument follows keyword argument` while pointing at the groupby code line.

The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('MEM096_bahl.csv', parse_dates=["TRADE_ENTRY_DATE"])

x=df['KATS_TIME'] 
hour=x//100000000

mins=x//1000000-hour*100

sec=(x-(x//1000000)*1000000)//10

df['hour']=hour 
df['mins']=mins
df['sec']=sec

df = df.drop(columns=['KATS_TIME'])

TOTAL_RATE=(df['TRADE_QTY'])*(df['TRADE_RATE'])
df['TOTAL_TRADE_RATE'] = TOTAL_RATE  


df = df.groupby(by=['TRADE_ENTRY_DATE'], ['SYMBOL_CODE'], ['hour'],['mins'], as_index=False)['TOTAL_TRADE_RATE'].sum()   


df.to_excel(r'E:\downloads\Machine Learning\2nd ass.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

The "groupby" function in pandas should receive a list of columns to group by, rather than a separate argument for each column. You can solve that by changing your groupby statement to the one given below

```py
df = df.groupby(by=['TRADE_ENTRY_DATE', 'SYMBOL_CODE', 'hour', 'mins'], as_index=False)['TOTAL_TRADE_RATE'].sum()
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain at least what you changed and how that solves the problem